# Replace nested multiple objects in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i have this document in mongodb, and want to replace all `435` objects in all documents with new objects with key `988` and the content of object `988` is same of `435` but changing only `name` property, how can i do this in mongodb?

```
{
  item: {
    _id: ObjectId("009"),
    subItems:
    {
      "435": {
        value: "item2",
        name: "item2"
      }
    }
  },
  item: {
    _id: ObjectId("004"),
    subItems:
    {
      "123": {
        value: "item1",
        name: "item1"
      },
      "435": {
        value: "item2",
        name: "item2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rename `$rename`

`db.collection.update( {}, { $rename: { "item.subItems.435": "item.subItems.498" } } )`

PS make changes according to your document structure.